# How to stop indexing/crawling for Shop Checkout Summaries?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I have a small shop checkout that uses cookies for my cart and after the payment is done it generates a unique order-id creates an "overview" page with an url like this:

`http://localhost:8180/app_dev.php/shop/checkout-done/78/STSNG-FG9L9`. `78` ist the db id for the cart and `STSNG-FG9L9` is the order id. To some extent, this should make it quite hard for anyone that doesn't have the order id AND the database id (which is not told to the customer anywhere except in the url) to guess the url and see their old cart.

However, I assume google and other bots tend to index these pages anyway, is there a reliant way to block ALL (potentially harmful) bots from crawling this site, as per `<meta>` it can get ignored by the bots. Does `robots.txt` stop them?

How would the `robots.txt` look like when I want to block all urls that look like `/checkout-WHATEVERCOMESHERE`

I have this, how can I check it works?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: *checkout-*
```

This is an issue as I want users be able to shop without any login or signup.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Search Console's robots.txt tester
[image]

You should be able to use:

`User-agent: *
Disallow: *checkout*`